# Log4j2 - No name attribute provided for Logger properties

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Im migrating a legacy application from log4j1 to log4j2.
But after update all the usage classes and configurations an error was ocurring when start the aplication

logger.properties:

```
status = debug
strict = true
name= config

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = AConsole
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %-5r %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = log/logicload.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = log/logicload-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %-5p [%t] %-17c{2} (%13F:%L) - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

logger.rolling.name = com.infineon.logicload
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = true
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
logger.rolling.appenderRef.console.ref = AConsole

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = AConsole
```

Error:

```
2022-07-29 12:51:41,174 main DEBUG Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
2022-07-29 12:51:41,174 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@2353b3e6 OK
2022-07-29 12:51:41,253 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=55054057
2022-07-29 12:51:41,255 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=55054057,component=StatusLogger
2022-07-29 12:51:41,257 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=55054057,component=ContextSelector
2022-07-29 12:51:41,259 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=55054057,component=Loggers,name=com.infineon.logicload
2022-07-29 12:51:41,261 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=55054057,component=Loggers,name=
2022-07-29 12:51:41,262 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=55054057,component=Appenders,name=AConsole
2022-07-29 12:51:41,263 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=55054057,component=Appenders,name=RollingFile
2022-07-29 12:51:41,264 main DEBUG org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock supports precise timestamps.
2022-07-29 12:51:41,264 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=55054057] at URI /workspaces/ebsprep-logicload/app/cfg/logger.properties (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4e268090) with optional ClassLoader: null
2022-07-29 12:51:41,265 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2022-07-29 12:51:41,265 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=55054057, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4e268090] started OK.
2022-07-29 12:51:41,271 main DEBUG Reconfiguration started for context[name=55054057] at URI file:/workspaces/ebsprep-logicload/app/cfg/logicload.properties (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4e268090) with optional ClassLoader: null
2022-07-29 12:51:41,271 main DEBUG Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@1eb5174b
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No name attribute provided for Logger properties
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.createLogger(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:264)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.build(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:180)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:35)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:304)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:467)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:325)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:690)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfigLocation(LoggerContext.java:679)
    at com.infineon.logicload.LogicLoad.main(LogicLoad.java:87)
2022-07-29 12:51:41,273 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=55054057, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4e268090]
```

Reading the question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566382/errorno-name-attribute-provided-for-log4j2-properties-customisation) I already try to use the same configurations but the error was the same.

**Updated on 08-04-2022**
The origin of my problem was related to the instalation process of the application.
This app has a lot of folders created by the instalation process, and in one stepp some old files like the logicload.properties was renamed.

Comment: Your application is not using the `log4j.properties` file but a `logger.properties` file and a `logicload.properties` file. The configuration using the first one succeeds and fails for the second one.

Comment: Giovane, as previously stated, the error is in the `logicload.properties` file, can you add it to the question?

Comment: I find the origin of problem, I will put on the principal post to keep documented